# Speech to text in Electron

Tags: text, electron, audio-recording, speech

Is there a way I can record audio in electron? 
I would also like to find out if it is possible to use Google speech API to convert speech to text in electron

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way I can record audio in electron?

Of course. Electron is based on Chromium and Node.js so you have access to:

- any APIs you can use in the browser (like the [`MediaStream` Recording API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Using_the_MediaStream_Recording_API))
- all Node.js features and libraries that work with Node.js (like [`node-audiorecorder`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-audiorecorder))

> I would also like to find out if it is possible to use Google speech API to convert speech to text in electron

Yes. There's [an official Node.js package](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-speech) for the Google Cloud Speech API. Again, an Electron-specific solution is not needed in this case.